# Image not showing in front page

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

This is postcontroller and index method use showing image on front end:

```
 public function index(){

        $user = Auth::user();
        $posts = Post::paginate(2);
        $images = Image::all();

      return view('post.index', compact('posts', 'user', 'images'));

}
public function create(){
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('post.create', compact('categories'));
}
public function store(Request $request){

     $user_id = Auth::user();
     $post_id = $user_id->post()->create($request->all());


$image=array();
if($files=$request->file('image')){
    foreach($files as $file){
        $name= time() .$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('image',$name);

    Image::create([
        'image'     =>  $name,
        'post_id'   => $post_id->id,
    ]);

    }
}

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

This is my view file there post content show:

```html
@foreach($posts as $key=>$post) 
   
  <div class="col-sm-4 my-4">
       <div class="card center">
           <img class="card-img-top" src="img/user1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title">{{$post->title}}</h2>
             <p class="card-text">{{$post->category}}</p>
             <p class="card-text">{{$post->title}}</p>
         
                    @foreach($images as $image)
                      <p>{{$image->image}}</p>
                    @endforeach
          </div>        
        </div>

  </div>
  
   
  
  @endforeach
```

[This is table of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKZJe.png)

[This is post table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbg5Y.png)

Now the problem is when I am trying to fetch images its just show image name...but how can I proper show image of the front page.

This is my output file of browser....Image table nd post table are separate connect to foreign key...Images extension show in front page but image not show

Sorry My english is not good but i put code, view, table everything so anybody can understand easily....
[output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNHvh.png)

[Image table value in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Hjj.png)

Comment: show table value of image.

Comment: I added...check it -@SetKyarWaLar

Comment: Show your application and image folder structure.

Comment: The folder name should be `images` not `image`.

Comment: I did it..check my updated answer

Comment: i cleared all cache and php artisan migrate:fresh.....than it  work and saw images..thank you for giving me your valuable time -@SetKyarWaLar

Comment: but problem is samepost show 2 times...

Answer (score 2):

You have to first link the storage with public folder if it isn't

> php artisan storage:link

Then you can retrieve image by

```
<img src="{{ '/public/images/' . $image->image }}">
```

Here images is your image folder name which you use to store image.

Comment: @Nirav Patel for display image you have to write  like this. `<img src="{{ asset('images').'/' . $image->image }}">`

Comment: yes @JinalSomaiya you also write asset('images') is redirect you to the public folder so both are giving same result

Comment: I did it and images show but problem is all image show which is database...i want to particular post_id through fetch image...how can i do -@NiralPatel

Comment: @kinnariprajapati Because you retrieve all images from Image table, you have to specify for particular post id like `Image::where('post_id',$post_id)->get();` instead of `Image::all();`  Here $post_id is your particular post's id.

Comment: @kinnariprajapati Revert code to `Image::all();` and in you blade page check condition in images foreach loop for `@if($post->id == $image->post_id)`.

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Property [post_id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\resources\views\post\index.blade.php) this error show me -@NiralPatel

Comment: @kinnariprajapati - Are you sure that you have put your if condition inside this `@foreach($images as $image)` loop?

Comment: if i want to make anyone feature image and front page show only feature image..than what should i do?? -@NiralPatel

Comment: @kinnariprajapati Use `@break` before `@endif` in same loop, It will stop loop after it gets the first image.

Comment: When i click title of add than show all images..how can i do? -@NiralPatel

Comment: Need brief specification on that, can't understand wat you want.

Comment: only show title and feature image on front page..when user click the title than show all brief details, another image all....-@NiralPatel

Comment: For that you can create another page in which only clicked post will be displayed with post discription and all images

Comment: if i click one post than show all post details...if i click one link than open only that post -@NiralPatel

Comment: you can also attach the images to that page using `Image::where('post_id',1)->get();`  Here 1 is your dynamic post id

Answer (score 1):

According to your code images are saved under `image` folder. But, you are retrieving the `{{$image->image}}` which is not the correct path. That's why your images do not appear. You can use `url()` or `assert()` helpers. Or you can simply do `{{ '/images/' . $image->image }}` when you display by the loop.

Of course, you have to use img tag to appear as an image.

```
<img src="{{ '/images/' . $image->image }}">
```

**Update**
I read your code again and saw your images are saving inside the app root path. In your `store` method. Update `$file->move('image',$name)` to `$file->move(public_path('images'),$name)`. Now, we put your images to `public_path`. You have to re-upload and test it out again.

You can read more about assert helper [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-asset) and URL helper about [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-url).

Comment: I try this but output like this          /image/Desert.jpg

/image/Chrysanthemum.jpg -

Comment: Of course, it will be output. You have to put inside the `img` tag. I updated the answer @kinnariprajapati

Comment: Updated answer, base on your result. Try it out. Note, you should read what your code doing as well. Otherwise, you have to ask every detail.

Comment: I put image folder in the public folder

Comment: Storage::url('/images').$image->name

Comment: I want to particular post image than i was fetching all images database show -@SachinAghera

Answer (score 0):

If you save your image in storage then run below command:
php artisan storage:link

Then you can get image by

```
<p><img src="{{url('storage/images').'/'.$image->name}}"></p>
```

And If you save your image in public path then you can directly get image by

```
<img src="{{url('/images').'/'.$image->name}}"/>
```